# Location of iPhone without internet or mobile network

Tags: ios, geolocation, core-location

I need to find the physical location of an iPhone without network access. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your iPhone has GPS hardware built in ([or A-GPS](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2469121), [to be specific](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/iphone/iphone-faq/iphone-gps-definition-assisted-gps-how-gps-works-real-time-navigation.html)), which it will rely upon as a first resort when there is no internet or mobile network available.

Comment: so do we need to code seperately for GPS or it will be taken care by locationManager in case there is no wifi or network

Comment: whether you're using cell towers or WiFi routers or the GPS hardware, it should all be abstracted away by CoreLocation Manager.